# How to connect to the corner of a rectangular node with a thick line without overlap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to connect a thick line with the corner of a rectangular node.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node (rect) at (0,0) [draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm,gray]{Rectangle};
   \draw[-,line width=2mm,red] (1cm,2cm)--(rect.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
However with an alignment of the right side of the line to the right side of the rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shift` the line according its width: `-.5\pgflinewidth`

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node (rect) at (0,0) [draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm,gray]{Rectangle};
   \draw[-,line width=2mm,red] ([xshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]rect.north east)--++(90:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]